# Unity Handheld.PlayFullScreenMovie() Not playing audio on Android

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I'm playing 2 videos, one at first time startup and another when you press a button. The video is playing fine but it doesn't have any audio.

I have tried adding in audio sources, swapping the video call to a Coroutine, changing the format of the videos. Nothing seems to be working, Anyone else had trouble with this?

Here is the call:

```
Handheld.PlayFullScreenMovie("Promo01.mov", Color.black, FullScreenMovieControlMode.CancelOnInput, FullScreenMovieScalingMode.AspectFill);
```

The files are in the StreamingAssets folder as well.

Answer (score 0):

The format of the video had something to do with it, converted the videos to MP4 which fixed the issue.